# What is the minimum memory requirement for splitting a TIFF file to multiple TIFF files?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, tiff

I have a query that what is the minimum memory requirement for splitting the tiff file to multiple tiff files. Is it running less than 2GB memory or not.

Have you any suggestion. Please reply its urgent.
Thanks
Dinesh Kumar

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You didn't tell us anything useful, like the size of the files you are dealing with and other requirements. Additionally, why should I care if you need an urgent reply?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323797/exception-throw-when-split-tiff-file-to-multi-tiff-files

Comment: How are you splitting your files?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, obviously, on how big the input tiff file is, and how it is going to be split up. Did you try to do any calculations? Or perhaps just try it out?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yes i develop an application which is split the tiff file to multiple tiff in development phase successfully but when i host it on local host(http://localhost/myApplication), myApplication is the virtual directory name, it gives the following error: Error occured while splitting file.System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occured in GDI+.   My windows server 2008 memory is 1.66 GB and free space available 160MB to 180MB. So i am asking you about memory.

Comment: That error doesn't say anything about memory. Why do you think memory is the problem?

Comment: Because of i have another server with 4GB RAM and this application is run on that server successfully. Now i am testing this on new server. It split the file in development phase but not at hosting time. Why this error occurs?

Comment: My tiff file size is 5 MB. And it didn't split the multi tiff files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting an `OutOfMemoryException` when trying to do this, then I would say your input TIFF is corrupt or partial.